# convert byte[] to string when upload a file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, upload

I have uploaded a file(image) by asp.net.
here is my code:

```
string imgpathpic =Convert .ToString (Session["imgpathpic"]);
long  sizepic =Convert .ToInt64 (Session["sizepic"]);
string extpic = Convert.ToString(Session["extpic"]);
byte[] inputpic = new byte[sizepic - 1];
inputpic = FileUpload2.FileBytes;
for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < sizepic; loop1++)
{
    displayStringPic = displayStringPic + inputpic[loop1].ToString();
}
```

I converted byte[] to string by that for,but after line  `displayStringPic = displayStringPic + inputpic[loop1].ToString();` i receive this exception  :

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop condition would be on the `length` of `inputpic` as you are accessing the element of  inputpic in the loop body

```
for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < inputpic.Length; loop1++)
{
    displayStringPic = displayStringPic + inputpic[loop1].ToString();
}
```

You should use string builder instead of string for optimum solution when there a lot of string concatenation, see [How to: Concatenate Multiple Strings (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(byte b in inputpic)
{
    sb.Append(b.ToString());
}
string displayStringPic = sb.ToString();
```

You better convert the byte array to string using `System.Text.Encoding`

```
var str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
```

**Note** Aside from converting the byte array to string, you can story the image as Image or in binary format.